# how to fix: "exports is not defined" & "require is not defined" error when importing package from vscode webview extension

Tags: webview, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode webview extension based on the [CatCoding example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-sample).

I'm trying to import an external node_module from cdn using the  tag. The package is loaded and I can use it, but in some of the imported functions there is an export of module and I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

I found out that someone has solved it by using the following "hack":
`<script>var exports = {};</script>`

So I tried it, and now I get kind of the same error about 'require':
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I'm just trying to do simple packages import, not sure why it happens, probably because it runs as a webview, maybe because of electron?

Any idea how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript package you are loading is using a module system, likely commonJS. The webview is just a normal webpage so you need to bring your own module support.

For this, you could use a bundler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or include a module loader such as [RequireJs](https://requirejs.org) directly.